# How to allow editing only 5 minutes after first edit to the cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am making a google spreadsheet for student council advisors in my school district to fill out. I am trying to make it so when a cell is filled out it isn't editable anymore. I found the following code that prevents cells from being edited after data is inputted.

```
function onEdit() {

var masterSheetName = "Master" 
var helperSheetName = "Helper" 
var firstDataRow = 1; 
var firstDataColumn = 1;

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var masterSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
if (masterSheet.getName() != masterSheetName) return;
var masterCell = masterSheet.getActiveCell();
if (masterCell.getRow() < firstDataRow || masterCell.getColumn() <     firstDataColumn) return;

var helperSheet = ss.getSheetByName(helperSheetName);
var helperCell = helperSheet.getRange(masterCell.getA1Notation());
var newValue = masterCell.getValue();
var oldValue = helperCell.getValue();

if (oldValue == "") {
helperCell.setValue(newValue);
} else {
masterCell.setValue(oldValue);
}
}
```

This works well enough, however I need a delay so that in case someone messes up inputting the information they have time to fix it. 
[I tried using utilities.Sleep()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3Xjn.png)  
to do this, however it seemed to have no effect. How can I delay the finalization of this information so the inputters have time to fix their responses?

Answer (score 1):

You can add another sheet to store the times at which a cell was first edited.
Try this

```
function onEdit() {
  var masterSheetName = "Master" 
  var helperSheetName = "Helper" 
  var timeSheetName = "Time" 
  var firstDataRow = 1; 
  var firstDataColumn = 1;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var masterSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (masterSheet.getName() != masterSheetName) return;
  var masterCell = masterSheet.getActiveCell();
  if (masterCell.getRow() < firstDataRow || masterCell.getColumn() < firstDataColumn) return;

  var helperSheet = ss.getSheetByName(helperSheetName);
  var timeSheet = ss.getSheetByName(timeSheetName);
  var helperCell = helperSheet.getRange(masterCell.getA1Notation());
  var timeCell = timeSheet.getRange(masterCell.getA1Notation());
  var newValue = masterCell.getValue();
  var oldValue = helperCell.getValue();
  var time = timeCell.getValue();

  if (oldValue == "" || time === "") {
    helperCell.setValue(newValue);
    timeCell.setValue(new Date());
  } else if(Date.now() - time < 5000) {
    helperCell.setValue(newValue);
  } else {
    masterCell.setValue(oldValue);
  }
}
```

Of course you should then also hide and protect the Helper and Time sheet so others can't edit them.

Answer (score 0):

Take a global variable(outside the function) and set the current datetime if the cell is blank(accessed for the first time).. I hope the below code helps.

```
var firstEntryTime = null;

function onEdit() {
    var currentDateTime = new Date();
    var masterSheetName = "Master" 
    var helperSheetName = "Helper" 
    var firstDataRow = 1; 
    var firstDataColumn = 1;

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var masterSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    if (masterSheet.getName() != masterSheetName) return;
    var masterCell = masterSheet.getActiveCell();
    if (masterCell.getRow() < firstDataRow || masterCell.getColumn() <     firstDataColumn) return;

    var helperSheet = ss.getSheetByName(helperSheetName);
    var helperCell = helperSheet.getRange(masterCell.getA1Notation());
    var newValue = masterCell.getValue();
    var oldValue = helperCell.getValue();

    if (oldValue == "") {
        helperCell.setValue(newValue);
        firstEntryTime = currentDateTime;
    } else if (currentDateTime.getMinutes() >= firstEntryTime.getMinutes() + 5) {
        masterCell.setValue(oldValue);
    }
}
```